# Discord bot cannot see member updates

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have writing a discord bot to mess around with using discord.py and discord.ext.commands, and so far it has been working as intended. However, no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to see a member update.
Here is the code that sets up intents

```py
#declare our intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
#client settings, load intents
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", guild_subscriptions=True)
```

And here is the code that should see a member update

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print("just saw a member update!")
```

I have also enabled both presence and member privileged intents in the application portal, and the bot has full admin privileges on the server and the highest rank below server owner. Is there an issue with the code, or is some other factor stopping it from seeing the updates? Does it need to be manually given some permission? It can see on_voice_state_update and on_message events using mostly the same code in the same server.

Comment: What did you do to invoke the `member_update` event?

Comment: I have tried changing roles, nicks, status. According to the API documentation it should be called when any of these are changed:
status
activity
nickname
roles
pending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a `Client` with the members intent enabled, and them immediately overwriting it with a `Bot` that has the default intents (and therefore the members intent disabled).

Pass your intents into the `Bot` creation instead.

```py
#declare our intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
#client settings, load intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", guild_subscriptions=True, intents=intents)
```